# Missing header error with Python requests but header defined

Tags: python, ansible, python-requests

I am trying to create an ansible module using the python requests library, and the module runs without errors but returns the response

"{\n  \"code\" : \"generic_err_missing_required_header\",\n  \"message\" : \"Missing header: [X-chkp-sid]\"\n}"

even though the header appears to be correctly defined.

Module code below:

```
from ansible.module_utils.basic import AnsibleModule
import requests

def somefunction(sid):
    url = '<someurl>'

    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-chkp-sid': sid,
    }

    data = {
        'type': 'tag'
    }

    response = requests.post(url,headers,data,verify=False,timeout=10)

    return response.content

def main():

    module_args = dict(
        sid = dict(type='str', required=True)
    )

    result = dict(
        changed=False,
        original_message='',
        message=''
    )

    module = AnsibleModule(
    argument_spec=module_args,
    supports_check_mode=True
    )

    if module.check_mode:
        return result

    sid = module.params['sid']

    result=somefunction(sid)

    module.exit_json(somefunction_output=result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have gotten a successful response using the ansible uri module and identical header/body parameters. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most arguments to `requests.post()` should be keyword-style args instead of plain positional args.

Try this instead:

```
response = requests.post(url,data=data,headers=headers,verify=False,timeout=10)
```

Comment: ah ok thanks! Works except that I also needed to use json=data rather than data=data otherwise there is a formatting error with the way I have it defined.

Answer (score 0):

`somefunction()` does not return anything, therefore the return value is `None`.

Perhaps you wanted `return requests.post(url,headers,data,verify=False,timeout=10)`?

Comment: edited the original question to be something different as I don't think the original question was useful for the community and I am now having a new issue with the same code

Comment: See my new answer.